# Can I compare boolean to integer in Ampscript? - Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can I compare boolean to integer in Ampscript?
in some programming language a boolean value is false/true but also 0/1 
how is in ampscript?

for instance, 
can I do this   %%myboolvar%% < 1?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use 0/1 as boolean values in AMPScript.

For example, the condition below is verified:

```
%%[
set @a = 1
  if @a THEN
  ...
  ENDIF
]%%
```

And to answer your second question, yeah you can do it. In the example below, the condition is verified as well:

```
%%[
set @a = 'true'
  if @a < 1 THEN
   ...
  ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: for instance, could I use this comparing in an exclusion script?

Comment: Don't see exactly what you want to achieve and why not comparing directly with a 0/1 value. But yeah, can't see why you can't use it..